# FBSDK Share Dialog is not working React-native ios simulator

Tags: facebook, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I'm try to add FBSDK and try to implement Share URL on facebook with the Xcode simulator. But it always return `Share operation was cancelled` following is my code

```
const shareLinkContent = {
  contentType: 'link',
   contentUrl: "https://facebook.com",
contentDescription: 'Facebook sharing is easy!',
};

var tmp = this;
ShareDialog.canShow(shareLinkContent).then(

  function(canShow) {
    console.log(canShow)
    if (canShow) {
      return ShareDialog.show(shareLinkContent);
    }
  }
).then(
  function(result) {
    console.log(result)
    if (result.isCancelled) {
      alert('Share operation was cancelled');
    } else {
      alert('Share was successful with postId: '
        + result.postId);
    }
  },
  function(error) {
    alert('Share failed with error: ' + error.message);
  }
);
}
```

This is the HTML button fro share

```
<Button
onPress={() => this.shareLinkWithShareDialog()}
title="share"
color="#841584"
accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't test it on simulator, you need to test this feature on real device, where Facebook app is already installed.

Comment: if FB app is not installed how can we manage that situation ??

Comment: @DileepaChandima you need go to app store and install Facebook app on real device